# Can we make a folder and its contents remain locked for certain times of the day and unlocked for the rest of the time?

Tags: encryption, directory

Suppose I have a Games folder. I don't want to waste my time on games. So is there someway that the folder remains inaccessible for most of the day, and only becomes accessible for say 3 hours after 11 o'clock.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Sounds like one of those awesome hacks you do :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution could be setting up cronjobs to lock/unlock the game directory. To do so follow the steps below.

1. Make sure cron-daemon is installed

`sudo apt-get install cron`

2. Prepare the game directory to be owned by root (alter the paths to fit your situation)

```
sudo chown -v root:root ~/GameDirectory
sudo chmod -v u+rwx ~/GameDirectory
sudo chmod -v go-rwx ~/GameDirectory
```

3. Setting up the cronjob to run for root

Start editing the cronjob by issuing following command:

`sudo crontab -e`

Add the folowing lines into the editor:

```
00 11 * * * chmod go+rwx ~/GameDirectory
00 14 * * * chmod go-rwx ~/GameDirectory
```

The above lines will make the cronjob unlock the directory at 11 am (hour setting is the second number from the left 0-23 hr style) and lock the directory at 2 pm.

Be advised that, since you have the ability to elevate your rights with sudo, you still need discipline to not overgo your own restrictions.

I never did set up cronjobs myself yet so if anyone finds an error in my solution, comment on it and I will correct it.

Comment: Wellcome to Ask Ubuntu. If it worked for you you could be so kind to accept the answer.

Comment: Does accepting the answer discourage others from answering? Just clarifying.

Comment: It should not, there surely serveral ways to solve that. And you can even switch the accept if someone provides a better solution.

Comment: Your answer is good. But if you find something more strict, please do write. I have a fear that when the urge is strong, sudo nautilus will be used by me to go past this mechanism.

Comment: Just made my day, hahaha. Will do for sure :)

Comment: @Videonauth Isn't one way to prevent him from elevating his rights to also encrypt that folder with some other  password, which he won't know (the password will be set by friend, who won't give it to him or whatever) and so to change the rights he would need that password? I would need this too, but for websites :D

Comment: This would'nt keep you from peeking into the crontab itself and for working there would be the password supplied anyways.

Comment: @Videonauth Ahh, shame. But there has to be a way to achieve it :)